# merging for LASSO for categorical variables

Tags: lasso

```
                              s0
```

(Intercept)             0.2991246444

animalDog              -0.0006095736

mfMale                  .

age                    -0.0357061834

in.month2               .
in.month3               .
in.month4               .
in.month5               .
in.month6               .
in.month7               .
in.month8               .
in.month9               .
in.month10              .
in.month11              .
in.month12              .
in.reasonPublic Assist -0.1980702921
in.reasonStray          .
in.intact1              .

In this LASSO coefficient estimates, in.reasonStray is being merged with the base level. in.reason and in.month are both categorical variables with 3 levels and 12 levels. So, one level is chosen to be the base level.in.reasonStray is merged with the base level.

So, it may be hard to interpret the base level if so many levels are merged.

But, what about in.month variable? The coefficients for every level is 0, so does that mean every level is being merged with the base level as well?